# How to map inner animations into layers in flash files?

Tags: export, flash, layer

The problem is that I've made some `Flash MovieClips` and animated some parts of those movies (like eyes winking animation) inside some other MCs (like **head** or **body**)
Now when I try to export them into PNG Sequence, its not applicable... because in the main stage there is just one frame and when I export as PNG Sequence it exports just one frame...
Is there any way to map all animations into some layers in the main time line or any other way to export them as Image as it plays normally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can convert nested animations using [Google Swiffy](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)

I made one that is only one frame long but has a nested MovieClip to prove it:

See the [example html output](http://swiffypreviews.googleusercontent.com/view/o/62f199c7-2599-463b-9acb-c210ca5c7ece/test.html)

Comment: nice tool, but how to convert it back to flash or Images sequence?

Comment: Hmm my example was using some vectors, can you maybe try to create a simple movie with some bitmaps in it, then see if it exports them?

Comment: the website says - Swiffy supports many common SWF features such as vector graphics, embedded fonts, images and timeline animation.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work... :( the SWF I have is made of so many nested MCs... When I export it using the tool, it exports just HTML containing so many JSon codes inside it...

Comment: oh damn, i can't think of another way i've only used swiffy in the past